# Production push notifications stop working after having previously worked

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I’m providing this question and answer because I’ve not seen the problem I ran into with the fairly common ‘APNS not working problem’ and perhaps my experience could help others.

One of my apps that I have in the store uses push notifications. Version 1 of the app was working just fine. No problems.

I created version 1.1, tested it on the sandbox APNS (worked fine) and submitted it. Sometime after 1.1 was approved I noticed push notifications weren’t working. My device was not receiving any push notifications, nor was any other user. That naturally led me to believe I’d screwed up something with the certificates or something like that when I created v 1.1. I checked all the normal things - sandbox vs production, certificates, provisioning profiles, etc. No dice.

--My server setup

I’m doing the interaction with the APNS servers myself and whenever I send an APNS message to Apple I got a positive response. My server code opens a connection to the APNS gateway, sends an APNS message for every device that needs one, then closes the connection.

(this next bit is key to the problem)

In the user record in my DB, I keep track if the user installed the dev version of the app or the production version of the app. I keep this as a flag in the user record. I do this for ease of use.

For simplicity sake, I have one script that processes the development users and sends their APNS messages to the sandbox server and separate code that sends the production user’s APNS messages to the production APNS gateway.

All of that was working fine. I’ll save you all the recertification steps and other grief that I did.

As far as I could tell everything was working fine and everything was set up correctly. So I followed the advice of Ms. Rand:  “Contradictions do not exist. Whenever you think that you are facing a contradiction, check your premises. You will find that one of them is wrong.”

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Good post. Would linking to the other "APNS not working problems" add to the helpfulness of this thread?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As to linking to other Q/A's, there are so many of these I don't know how helpful it would be to link to them and they all seem to be the same types of things which I alluded to: sandbox vs gateway; using the right cert; etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After too many hours trying to figure out what was going on I finally determined the problem.

1. I had turned a development user (my wife’s iPhone) into a production user as I thought she had downloaded the production release of the app
2. For this user, my server was using the deviceID generated from the development app and sending that to the production APNS server
3. Whenever I would send that device ID to the production server as one of the APNS messages, even though I would get a positive response from the servers, none of the APNS messages to any other devices would work.

Once I flipped her user record back to be a development device, everything began working again.

I verified multiple times that this was the problem.

So, it appears that using a deviceID that’s intended for sandbox APNS interaction and sending it to the production APNS really screws things up.

Hope this helps somebody in the future.